# Opening a web app from another web app - server side

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, proxy, opennms

I have a web application (say WA1 ) which is hosted in cloud.

I have a proxy java application running in my private network and communicates with WA1 .

On click of a button in the cloud application WA1, I want to open another webapp (say WA2) which is running in my private.

How can I do this ?

I have REST connectivity between WA1 and WA2 through the proxy.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open' another webapp?

Comment: I want to access the webpage and do all actions in that.

Comment: May be a simple hyperlink, on click of which proxy will be hit and proxy will redirect to WA2 - case of 301 redirect?